# SOLVED Magento 1.9 cannot place order "Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back"

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, debugging, transaction

I have Magento 1.9.2.4 and something is wrong with onePage checkout. I've got gift card extension installed on it. It is a custom one but 100% it works fine.

The problem is that I can't place the order and the only one output I get in logs is:

> User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back 
>   in
>   C:\Users\blablabla\Documents\sites\mywebsite\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php
>   on line 4039

I tried to debug it and I found that the problem is in these line:

> $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote());
>   $service->submitAll();

After it tries to submit everything - it crashes.

I went deeper to sales/service_quote model and found that everything crash after:

> $transaction->save();

C:\Users\blablabla\Documents\sites\mywebsite\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php

But as I am new to Magento, I have no idea what this model actually does and how to fix it...

Simply when I press "Pay & Place order" button it sends ajax to the web server and respond successfully, but nothing happens after that.

I spent 3 days trying to understand what's wrong with this, so I would really appreciate if someone gives me a hand. I am not really advanced in debugging, so I would really happy if you could give me an advice on how to search the reason of bugs like this. Thanks

P.s. I am using Xampp

Comment: What was the change that you made when this issue started?

Comment: What's the gift card extension ? How can you say it works 100% fine is you're not getting this issue ?

Comment: Whys this marked as solved when theres no answers? I have the same error and would like to know how to fix it